# Ejecutar petición AJAX sin importar la url

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy trabajando con Laravel 5.4 y tengo la siguiente petición AJAX:

```
function machineBrandList(){

        var id_maquina = $(this).val();
        var url = $(this).data().url + id_maquina;
        $.get(url, function(data){
            nu_useful_width_min.value = data.nu_useful_width_min;
            nu_useful_width_max.value = data.nu_useful_width_max;
            nu_core_diameter.value = data.nu_core_diameter;
            nu_weight_supported_max.value = data.nu_useful_width_min; 
        });
    }


    $('#machine_type').change(machineBrandList);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="div_machine_converter_select" class="uk-text-left uk-width-1-4">
        {!! Form::label('machine_type', 'Indique su maquina') !!}
        {!! Form::select('machine_type',['' => 'Seleccione'],null,['class' => 'uk-select', 'data-url' =>'maquinas/', 'disabled'])!!}
    </div>
```

Esta petición debe ejecutarse en múltiples URL's que corresponden a diferentes formularios (editar, clonar, etc). En este momento me funciona para el formulario de crear, la ruta en Laravel esta configurada de la siguiente manera:

las URL's serian

http://app.dev/users/datasheet/create -
http://app.dev/users/datasheet/6/edit - 
http://app.dev/users/datasheet/clone/6

```
Route::get('datasheet/create/maquinas/{id?}', 'Datasheet\DatasheetController@obtenerDatosMaquinas')->name('maquinas');
```

Lo ideal sería que esta petición Ajax funcione para las 3 rutas descritas anteriormente.

¿Cómo hacer para que esta función pueda usarse en las URL's descritas?, ¿Se deben crear las rutas respectivas en el archivo de rutas *web.php* de Laravel?

Comment: Cual sería otra URL? Esa otra URL tiene que apuntar al mismo controlador? No termino de entender lo que necesitás.

Comment: gracias @azeos, en efecto todas las url's deben apuntar al mismo controlador, el tema es saber si es posible que esa petición ajax pueda funcionar en la vista X sin necesidad de crear mas rutas.

Comment: Perdón pero sigo sin entender. En otra vista la consulta de AJAX va a utilizar otra URL? Por qué no repetís simplemente el código JS en las distintas vistas? Podrías poner un ejemplo de lo que estás diciendo?

Comment: @azeos gracias, el tema es el siguiente, poder reutilizar esa petición ajax en multiples vistas, en mi caso particular necesito poderla ejecutar en la vista de crear, editar y clonar, ya que las tres utilizan el mismo formulario y la misma estructura de campos todo hecho en laravel 5.4. Por el momento esta funcionando en la vista de crear porque tengo definida la ruta en laravel, la idea es que en una sola ruta funcione el ajax para los 3 formularios y así no duplicar mas código, es eso posible. El parametro url puede ser dinamico?

Comment: La consulta de `AJAX` se hace a la `ruta` que tenés definida. Es indistinto desde que vista la estás ejecutando. Con incluir ese bloque de `JS` en todas las vistas es suficiente. El parámetro URL de la consulta de AJAX puede ser dinámico, pero de donde lo obtendrías?

Comment: @azeos, En mi caso el problema es que uso webpack asi que no inserto js directamente en la vista sino en un archivo app.js global que webpack genera, no he podido entender como hacer digamos que esta ruta var url = "create/maquinas/"+id_maquina; pueda adaptarse dependiendo de la url en la que me encuentre, gracias por la ayuda soy nuevo en estos temas!!

Comment: Insisto, editá tu pregunta y poné un ejemplo de que otras URLs necesitás o desde que otras URLs vas a acceder. Si accedés desde `sitio.com/url1` o `sitio.com/url2` no afecta en nada la consulta `AJAX`, porque lo único que importa es que la URL que tenés en el código `JS` coincida con la URL que tenés definida en tus rutas. Si lo que estoy diciendo no responde tu pregunta, por favor da más ejemplos de lo que necesitás.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70586/discussion-between-darwin-gomez-and-azeos).

Answer (score 0):

Puedes poner un data en el elemento #machine_type y recuperarlo:

En el html (ejemplo):

```
<input id="machine_type" name="machine_type" value="1" data-url="{{asset(‘create/maquinas/‘)}}"/>
```

en javascript:

```
$('#machine_type').change(function(){
        var url =$(this).data().url + id_maquina;
        var id_maquina = $(this).val();
        $.get(url, function(data){
            nu_useful_width_min.value = data.nu_useful_width_min;
            nu_useful_width_max.value = data.nu_useful_width_max;
            nu_core_diameter.value = data.nu_core_diameter;
            nu_weight_supported_max.value = data.nu_useful_width_min; 
        });

     });
```

De esta forma reutilizas el AJAX. Del mismo modo que haces con la url puedes hacer con otros parámetros.

Comment: Gracias @PedroPrada, lo intente de esa manera pero aun el problema persiste, machine_type es un campo select, pero no he podido lograr que este me funcione para las URL's que describi en el problema, de que forma ya que siempre me dice http://app.dev/users/datasheet/maquinas/9 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Mira ahora con la modificación en la ruta

Comment: Gracias @PedroPrada, lo intente como me comentaste pero ahora sale un error GET http://app.dev/users/datasheet/%3C?php%20echo%20e(asset(%E2%80%98maquinas/%E2%80%98));%20?%3E9 405 (Method Not Allowed).

Comment: Porque la ruta la tìenes con POST. Si pones la ruta con GET solucionas el problema