# Problema Rutas de Laravel con Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy utilizando Laravel 5.4, tengo tres formularios (Crear – Editar - Clonar) y en los 3 necesito ejecutar la siguiente petición Ajax por tal motivo las url de cada formulario varían:

```
http://app.dev/users/datasheet/create
http://app.dev/users/datasheet/6/edit
http://app.dev/users/datasheet/6/clone
```

Route.php:

```
Route::get('datasheet/create/machine_brand_list/{option?}', 'Datasheet\DatasheetController@getMachineBrandList');
```

Controlador.php:

```
public function getMachineBrandList(Request $request, $option){

        if($option == 'Rollo' && $request->ajax()){
                $id = auth()->id();            
                $machinesBrand = Machine::where('user_id','=',$id)->get();
                return response()->json($machinesBrand);  
         }
    }
```

Ajax:

```
function infoMachinesBrand(){

            var selectValor = this.value;
            var url = "create/machine_brand_list/"+selectValor;
            //var url = "edit/machine_brand_list/"+selectValor;
            //var url = "clone/machine_brand_list/"+selectValor;            

            if (selectValor == 'Rollo') {                
                //$("#div_machine_converter_select").show();
                $('#machine_type').prop("disabled", false);
                $.get(url, function(data){
                    $('#machine_type').append('<option value="">Seleccione</option>');
                        $.each(data,function(index, value){
                           $('#machine_type').append('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.dsc_name+'</option>');                                
                        });

                }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        console.log(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown);
                });

            } else {
                //$("#div_machine_converter_select").hide();
                $('#machine_type').prop("disabled", true);
                $('#machine_type').empty()
                clear = document.getElementById('nu_useful_width_min').value = "";
                clear = document.getElementById('nu_useful_width_max').value = "";
                clear = document.getElementById('nu_core_diameter').value = "";
                clear = document.getElementById('nu_weight_supported_max').value = ""; 
            }

        }

        $('#product_type').change(infoMachinesBrand);
```

En el código del Ajax expuesto se aprecia que en la variable URL tengo que anteponer la última parte de la url para que me funcione la petición Ajax, pero necesito no depender de ello ya que son tres formularios donde debo ejecutar la misma función, en ese caso ¿Cómo crear en Laravel una ruta que me permita ejecutar dicha función sin importar la url en la que me encuentre?, ¿Es esto posible?.

Comment: Esta pregunta ya fue realizada anteriormente: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/125994/ejecutar-petici%C3%B3n-ajax-sin-importar-la-url Para realizar preguntas debes basarte en el documento [ask]. Evita realizar varias preguntas en este caso te sugiero mejorar tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: Puedes crear un controlador y una ruta tipo resource, y para acceder a cada una de ellas solo cambiaría el metodo por el que viaja, sea post, get, put, patch o delete Puedes ver mayor información [aquí en la documentación de laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers)

Answer (score 1):

Si, se puede generar una ruta genérica, para los 3 casos:

```
Route::get('getMachineBrandList/{option?}', 'Datasheet\DatasheetController@getMachineBrandList');
```

Y luego, en la llamada Ajax, se setea la url correspondiente y listo:

```
function infoMachinesBrand(){

    var selectValor = this.value;
    var url = "getMachineBrandList/"+selectValor;
```

Entiendo que este Ajax se utiliza para cargar las opciones de un Select (o lista desplegable) tras algún evento, por lo que debería ser independiente de las urls que se utilizan en los formularios (creación, edición o clonación), para procesar posteriormente los datos.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tienes mal escrita la ruta en ajax. por un lado quieres ejecutar rutas del estilo:

```
http://app.dev/users/datasheet/create
```

En el archivo rutas la ruta que tienes es:

```
datasheet/create/machine_brand_list/{option?}
```

Y en ajax la que hay es

```
create/machine_brand_list/"+selectValor
```

Se parecen en muy poco. Deben tener la misma estructura, deben ser iguales